# why did the value of a change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook

**func_two**

```
def func_two(x):
    x[1][1] = x[2][1]
    x[2][1] = 0 
    return x

a = [[12, 11, 7, 13], [6, 0, 8, 3], [9, 4, 10, 2], [5, 14, 15, 1]]
print(a, ":before function")
b = func_two(a)
print(a, ":after function")
print(b, ":value of b")
```

output for this is

```
[[12, 11, 7, 13], [6, 0, 8, 3], [9, 4, 10, 2], [5, 14, 15, 1]] :before function
[[12, 11, 7, 13], [6, 4, 8, 3], [9, 0, 10, 2], [5, 14, 15, 1]] :after function
[[12, 11, 7, 13], [6, 4, 8, 3], [9, 0, 10, 2], [5, 14, 15, 1]] :value of b
```

why did the value of "a" change after the function?
how do I run the func_two without changing the variable outside the function (I haven't declared any variable as a global variable, this shouldn't happen)

**code that works correctly  func_one**

```
def func_one(x):
    x = [[3]]
    return x 

a = [[5]]
print(a, ":before function")

b = func_one(a)

print(a, ":after function")
print(b, ":value of b")
```

output for this is

```
[[5]] :before function
[[5]] :after function
[[3]] :value of b
```

**why is func_one working when func_two is not working ?**

Comment: You're expecting a lot more implicit copies than Python does. I recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - it's a great introduction to how Python variables and objects work.

Comment: thanks, @Wups that does solve my question.

Comment: and thanks @Monica,   --nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html--   this was a great read, I had no clue python handled variables this way.  this actually explains a lot of errors I have had earlier (i had earlier solved them by god know how (doing random things)) not knowing the actual cause of why the problem was happening!!!!   thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question has been answered in the comments by @user2357112 supports Monica, and by @Wups

answer

```
import copy

def transition(x):
    y = copy.deepcopy(x)
    y[1][1] = y[2][1]
    y[2][1] = 0 
    return y

a = [[12, 11, 7, 13], [6, 0, 8, 3], [9, 4, 10, 2], [5, 14, 15, 1]]

print(a, ":before function")

b = transition(a)

print(a, ":after function")
```